# Angular 2 Cannot read property undefined

Tags: angular, lodash

I have a simple search textbox and on value changed I am calling this function(I am using Lodash)

```
  onKeyCustomerSearch(event: any) {

    this.SearchCustomerString = event.target.value;

    this.customersView = _.clone(this.customersArray);
    this.customersView.paginatedCustomers = _.filter(this.customersView.paginatedCustomers, function (x) {
      return x.BusinessName.includes(this.SearchCustomerString);
    });
  }
```

I am getting Cannot read property 'SearchCustomerString' of undefined

However this is working!

```
  onKeyCustomerSearch(event: any) {

    this.customersView = _.clone(this.customersArray);
    this.customersView.paginatedCustomers = _.filter(this.customersView.paginatedCustomers, function (x) {
      return x.BusinessName.includes(event.target.value);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using function expression (FE) i would use arrow function `()=>` to retain `this`:

```
this.customersView.paginatedCustomers = _.filter(this.customersView.paginatedCustomers, 
                          (x) => x.BusinessName.includes(this.SearchCustomerString));
```

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this